# jquery money masking input with negative integer only

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask, jquery-mask

I am trying to mask input only with optional negative or positive integers. I tried using

```
jQuery(function($){
   $.mask.definitions['~']='[-]?';
   $("#eyescript").mask("~?999999999");
});
```

but this is allowing any character at the first place. (Eg: f12, -12, +12, /12, etc..)

I want the user to strictly use only '-' or any number in the first position.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I found the answer. Added one integer or negative sign as optional and reduced one 9 from the mask to satisfy the requirement.

`jQuery(function($){ 
    $.mask.definitions['~']='[0-9-?]'; 
    $("#eyescript").mask("~?99999999"); });`